# Can't run commands from bash script in for-loop

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to create a bash script that reads in subfolders within a folder and uses the subfolder as an input for a python program, but for some reason, it can't recognize some simple commands.

So just as a reference, the python program I have takes in two inputs: the subfolder it's taking in (folder **must only** have files in it) and an output file name.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/foo/bar/*
for folder in $PATH; do
        echo  "${folder##*/}"
        (cat "${folder##*/}" output.txt) | python3 program.py
done
```

I've ran the program by itself in the command line and it has worked numerous times, but for some reason this doesn't.

This is the resulting output:

```sh
$ bash fileread.sh
> File1
> fileread.sh: line 6: cat: command not found
> fileread.sh: line 6: python3: command not found
> File2
> fileread.sh: line 6: cat: command not found
> fileread.sh: line 6: python3: command not found
```

Clearly, the `echo` command works, but somehow the other two stopped working

Answer (score 2):

`PATH` is a reserved variable. By using it for your own purpose, bash can't find the commands anymore. Just use a different name.

Also, if you want to store a list, it makes IMO more sense to use an array:

```
p=(/foo/bar/*)
for folder in "${p[@]}"
...
```